# Alternative to Quizlet live that supports latex formulas

Tags: software

With [Quizlet Live](https://quizlet.com/features/live) you can play a flashcard game in classroom, where teams compete against each other. Since Quizlet doesn't seem to support rendering latex formulas, I am looking for a alternative with latex support.

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Do you need it to have four, large colored buttons with options on them? If you don't mind simple (smaller) radio buttons, you might check out itempool.com for live quizzing that supports LaTeX. [Note: I'll convert this to an answer if the OP says the large colored buttons aren't a deal breaker.]

Answer (score 1):

In case you're not able to find anything that natively supports the functionality you want, here's a hacky-yet-functional workaround:

1. Write the questions in LaTeX in an Overleaf document as multiple-choice questions with answer choices A, B, C, D.
2. On each Quizlet card, just enter "Question #_" in the question textbox and "A", "B", "C", "D" in the answer choice textboxes.
3. When you do the Quizlet during class, do a split-screen and put the Overleaf document side-by-side with the Quizlet, scrolling down to the next question as needed.

Essentially, the Overleaf document manages the questions and the Quizlet Live manages the competition.